# Is there a possibility in python to output column values as file names?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have the following df:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  3
2  4  6
```

Now I want to output column A values as file names.

```
fac_doc_template = XML

fac_details_xml_template = {A} 
{B}

#formatting
def series_to_fac_details_xml(s):
    return fac_details_xml_template.format(**s)


#for loop to output file as index names
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    details = series_to_fac_details_xml(row)
    with open(fr"C:\Users\Max12\Desktop\xml\pdfminer\UiPath\output\{index}.xml", "w") as f:
        f.write(fac_doc_template.format(fac_details=details))
```

My output now is: 0.xml, 1.xml, 2.xml.

However I would like my output files to be the following:

1.xml, 1.xml, 4.xml.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `'A'` value from the row, so:

```
#for loop to output file as index names
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    details = series_to_fac_details_xml(row)
    with open(fr"C:\Users\Max12\Desktop\xml\pdfminer\UiPath\output\{row['A']}.xml", "w") as f:
        f.write(fac_doc_template.format(fac_details=details))
```

Answer (score 0):

to get those file names change:

```
{index} -> {row['A']}
```

you might have issues with duplicate file names though. maybe create a folder based on index or use "w+" to truncate each file.